# How to implement key and salt for jmazzi/crypt_keeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, salt

I'm trying to implement [crypt_keeper](https://github.com/jmazzi/crypt_keeper) for a Ruby on Rails app. The docs don't tell me how to implement the key and salt.

How do I do it securely?

How long do they need to be?

Should they be the same for each column or generate a random one each time?

I've [asked](https://github.com/jmazzi/crypt_keeper/issues/78) on the issue tracker also

Comment: This has now been answered on the issue tracker https://github.com/jmazzi/crypt_keeper/issues/78 so no need to answer here unless there's more to add.